# ASP.NET to see if a number is even or odd

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the following code in a loop to find out if a variable is odd or even (only wanting to show the even results here) but I get the following error message "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" for the line:

```
<% if((leftCount % 2) = true) { %>
```

Here is the code in full:

```
<% var leftCount = 1;  %>           
            <% foreach (var i in DevelopmentJobs) { %>
                <% if((leftCount % 2) = true) { %>
                DO SOMETHING
                <% } %>

                <% } %>
           <% leftCount++; %>
```

Thanks

Comment: seems your `<% leftCount++; %>` is off the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if((leftCount % 2) = true) { %>
```

Should be:

```
<% if(leftCount % 2 == 0) { %>
```

Using a single = sign means you want to assign a value. Using double == means you're testing for a value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if((leftCount % 2) == 0`. You want to test if the modulo is 0, it's a mathematical expression.

And you need `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment)

Answer (score 1):

`leftCount % 2` resolves to an integer, not a boolean. You should test its value against the appropriate int value. In this case, if `leftCount` is divided by two, we are checking that its remainder is equal to zero, which would indicate it is odd or even.

```
 <% var leftCount = 1;  %>           
        <% foreach (var i in DevelopmentJobs) { %>
            <% if((leftCount % 2 == 0) { %>
            DO SOMETHING
            <% } %>

            <% } %>
       <% leftCount++; %>
```

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx